How do I run my powershell script from any directory? (Like in $profile but in its own .ps1 file)
My .ps1 script is just a simple multi-argument function, but I want to run this function anywhere like functions in $PROFILE but for tidiness and organisation's sake, I want it to be its own file. If where I put it affects my code, I'm making a cli for a package installer called mint. I tried many articles and posts, but none of them worked. Thanks!

If this is part of an application (mint?), then you should create a module. Avoid having something installed in one of the user's -many- profile scripts.

If it's a simple script, just Dot-Source it in your $PROFILE.
If it's more complex, check out Modules

I have this in my $PROFILE to recursively source all ps1 files in the scripts folders and subfolders.
$scripts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Users\username\PowerShell\Scripts\*.ps1"
foreach ($script in $scripts) { . $script.FullName }

